# Batch Script: Double Digit Number Less Than Single Digit

Tags: batch-file, numbers, compare

I'm new to batch scripting and don't understand why double digit numbers evaluate as less than single digit?

%weekdayOffPeakEnd% variable is 7 when echo'd.

I'm calling this sleepUntilOffPeak function from within a FOR loop (not shown) but I don't think that has any impact because I don't use any variables from this function anywhere else in the script. This function simply checks the current hour and "sleeps" until electricity rates are low again.

Thx

```
rem if not currently off-peak hours, wait (timeout) until electricity rates are lowest
:sleepUtilOffPeak
rem set DayofWeek and Hour variables
for /f %%a in ('wmic path win32_localtime get DayOfWeek /format:list ^| findstr "="') do (set %%a)
for /f %%a in ('wmic path win32_localtime get Hour /format:list ^| findstr "="') do (set %%a)
rem echo Day of week^: %DayOfWeek%
echo Hour^: %Hour%

rem set OffPeak variables
set /a weekdayOffPeakEnd=07
echo weekdayOffPeakEnd^: %weekdayOffPeakEnd%
set /a weekdayOffPeakStart=23
set /a weekendOffPeakEnd=15
set /a weekendOffPeakStart=19

set weekday=true
if "%DayOfWeek%" EQU "0" set weekday=false
if "%DayOfWeek%" EQU "6" set weekday=false
rem echo weekday^: %weekday%

if %weekday% equ true (
    echo Today is a weekday
    if Hour LSS weekdayOffPeakEnd (
        echo %Hour% is less than off-peak end^:  %weekdayOffPeakEnd%. Returning...
        exit /B 0
    ) else (
        if Hour GEQ weekdayOffPeakStart (
            echo %Hour% is greater than or equal to off-peak start^: %weekdayOffPeakStart%. Returning...
            exit /B 0
        ) else ( rem Hour is between 07 and 23
            rem sleep until offPeak then return
            set /a sleepTime=23-%Hour%
            set /a sleepSeconds=%sleepTime%*3600
            echo Going to sleep for %sleepSeconds% seconds
            timeout /t %sleepSeconds%
            exit /B 0
        )
    )
) else ( rem weekday equ false
    echo Today is a weekend
    if Hour LSS weekendOffPeakEnd (
        echo %Hour% is less than off-peak end^: %weekendOffPeakEnd%. Returning...
        exit /B 0
    ) else (
        if Hour GEQ weekendOffPeakStart (
            echo %Hour% is greater than or equal to off-peak start^: %weekendOffPeakStart%. Returning...
            exit /B 0
        ) else ( rem Hour is between 15 and 19
            rem sleep until offPeak then return
            set /a sleepHours=%weekendOffPeakStart%-%Hour%
            echo sleepHours^: %sleepHours%
            set /a sleepSeconds=%sleepHours%*3600
            echo Going to sleep for %sleepSeconds% seconds
            timeout /t %sleepSeconds%
            echo All done sleeping. Returning...
            exit /B 0
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Use this syntax `if %DayOfWeek% EQU 0 set weekday=false`

Comment: When you use `Set /A` remove any surrounding percents from variable names. Another piece of advice is for you to read up on delayed expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many examples like this:

```
if Hour LSS weekdayOffPeakEnd (
```

This compares the literal   `Hour` to the literal `weekdayOffPeakEnd`

You need

```
if %Hour% LSS %weekdayOffPeakEnd% (
```

Further, if you *change* the value of any variable within a *code block* (parenthesised code) then you need to retrieve the *changed* value using `!var!` having invoked `delayed expansion` (use `search` to locate many SO items)

Also, you observe that `set /a var=07` will set the variable to `7`, not `07`. It's important to understand the difference between `set /a` and `set`. `set /a` resolves the value to be assigned and then assigns that value *as a string* to the variable, suppressing leading zeroes. `set` assigns the literal including leading zeroes.

This leads to two consequences. First, a value that starts with `0` is assigned by `set/a` as an *OCTAL* value, so `08` and `09` will be *invalid*. And second, `if %var% op val` will attempt to convert *both* arguments of the operator to numeric to perform the comparison, and if *both* conversions are successful, then the comparison is executed as a *numeric* comparison, otherwise it's executed as a *string comparison* where the characters are matched serially from the left.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance and explaining how if statements are evaluated. All of the if else statements are working now and I've hardcoded the set /a sleepHours=7-Hour statement to avoid 07 being interpreted as an octal. Unfortunately, sleepHours is not assigned any value. Please advise.

Comment: You need to invoke delayedexpansion [hundreds of SO articles about that - use the search feature] in order to display or use the run-time value of any variable that's changed within a parenthesised series of instructions (aka "code block").

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned; I'm already using SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion. The sleepHours variable isn't used outside of its own code block. It is created and (unsuccessfully) set inside the final else statement for either the weekday or weekend parent code block. None of the following results in the sleepHours variable being populated: set /a sleepHours=23-Hour, set /a sleepHours=23-%Hour% or set /a sleepHours=23-!Hour!

Comment: The code block starts at `if %weekday% equ true (` and terminates at the last `)` of your posted code. Since `sleephours` is assigned within the block at `set /a sleepHours=%weekendOffPeakStart%-%Hour%` , any further reference to its contents must be as `!sleephours!`. `%sleephours%` will have the then-current value of `sleephours` substituted *at the time the entire block is encountered*. Note that in a `set /a`, `%var%` refers to the value of the variable when the block was encountered, `!var!` its current value as may have been modified, & `var` can also be used to mean "the current value".

Comment: Much thanks. You last comment above triggered the light bulb in my brain :)